# How to release an Excel Object

Tags: c#, excel, for-loop, foreach, marshalling

In my code below I have a commented out foreach loop that works except it does not release the excel object due to the background enum.  So I am trying to convert it to a for loop but up until this point I have avoided 'for' loops and I can't seem to get mine to work.  I am just pointing out that I know it is broke.

I did comment out the broken 'for' loop and it runs and all works as expected except I can't release the excel objects...
My question, I have tried so many different examples but I can not release the excel object from my task manager and it remains open in the back ground.

- I use the "One Dot" rule
- I'm using a try/final
- I have tried many different Marshal.ReleaseComOjbect(obj), examples from the web
- I am using a 'for loop' (not a foreach loop) so no hidden Enum object

Thank you for any assistance, education

My code:

```
public static List<ExcelObject> listOfExcelObjects = new List<ExcelObject>();
    public static void txtSearchBar_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Excel.Application excel = null;
        Excel.Workbooks workbooks = null;
        Excel.Workbook workbook = null;
        Excel.Sheets sheets = null;
        Excel.Worksheet worksheet = null;
        Excel.Range range = null;

        try
        {
            excel = new Excel.Application();
            workbooks = excel.Workbooks;
            workbook = workbooks.Open(GlobalObject.filePath, Notify: false, ReadOnly: true);
            sheets = workbook.Sheets;

            for (int i = 1; i < sheets.Count; i++)
            {
                worksheet = sheets.Item[i];
                if (worksheet.Visible == Excel.XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetVisible)
                {
                    Form_MainForm.thisForm.cmbx_WorkSheet.Items.Add(sheets.Item[i].Name);
                    if (worksheet.Name == "UNIT FEEDER")
                    {
                        Form_MainForm.thisForm.cmbx_WorkSheet.Text = worksheet.Name;
                        worksheet.Select();

                        Form_MainForm.thisForm.txtBox_StartingRow.Text = $"11";
                        Form_MainForm.thisForm.txtBox_EndingRow.Text = $"{_Events.EndOfRow()}";

                        range = worksheet.Range[$"A{Int32.Parse(Form_MainForm.thisForm.txtBox_StartingRow.Text)}", $"A{Int32.Parse(_Events.EndOfRow())}"];
                        for (int j = 1; j < range.Cells.Count; j++)
                        {
                            _Events.listOfExcelObjects.Add(new ExcelObject() { FeederNumber = range.Cells.Item[j] });
                        }

                        //foreach (Excel.Range j in worksheet.Range[$"A{Form_MainForm.thisForm.txtBox_StartingRow.Text}", $"A{_Events.EndOfRow()}"].Cells)
                        //{
                        //    _Events.listOfExcelObjects.Add(new ExcelObject() { FeederNumber = j.Value });
                        //}

                        Form_MainForm.thisForm.grd_DataGridView.DataSource = _Events.listOfExcelObjects;

                    }

                }

            }

        }
        finally
        {

            releaseObject(range);
            releaseObject(worksheet);
            releaseObject(sheets);
            releaseObject(workbook);
            releaseObject(workbooks);
            releaseObject(excel);
            //Marshal.ReleaseComObject(range);
            //Marshal.ReleaseComObject(worksheet);
            //Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sheets);
            //Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);
            //Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbooks);
            //Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel);
        }


    }

    private static void releaseObject(object obj)
    {
        if (obj != null && Marshal.IsComObject(obj))
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
        }
        obj = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close Excel:

```
excel.Quit();
```

Comment: Hi Terry, I altered my code as follow, the quit does close one backgroud process but I still have two excel process that  remain open.  So I am still doing something wrong. releaseObject(range);
releaseObject(worksheet);
releaseObject(sheets);
if (workbook != null)
{
workbook.Close(false, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
}
releaseObject(workbook);
releaseObject(workbooks);
if (excel != null)
{
excel.Quit();
}
releaseObject(excel);

Comment: @AlanC are you sure those other processes aren't left over from earlier? Try to kill all Excel process and try your code again. I've had problems like that before myself. Excel is horrible about hanging around after automating it.

Comment: yes, thank you...  My EndOfRow() I didn't do any cleaning of that function.  I didn't know to clean when I created this function and I forgot about it...  thanks again

Answer (score 0):

For those who don't read the comment section 'such as myself'

I have a function EndOfRow() that I did not do any cleaning to release objects.  I didn't know about releasing objects when I created this function and I forgot about it.  Many hours spent on a simple oversight.

Leaving out the Quit() was also an oversight in my many attemts to resolve my issue but was not the main problem, EndOfRow() was...

So what I learned is to release the objects as soon as I am done using excel.

Thanks Terry